# Creating a count variable for NA cases in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, count, na

I have an R data frame including a few columns of numerical data with NA values too. See the example with  first 2 columns below. I want to create a new column (3rd one below called output) which shows an incremental count of NA values for each of my group variables. For example, region A has 2 NA values so it will show 1 and 2 next to the relevant rows. Region B has only one NA value so will show 1 next to it. If a region X has 10 NA values it should show 1,2,3 ... , 10 next to each case, as move down the data frame.

| Region | Value | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Region A | 5 | 0 |
| Region B | 2 | 0 |
| Region B | NA | 1 |
| Region A | NA | 1 |
| Region A | 9 | 0 |
| Region A | NA | 2 |
| Region A | 4 | 0 |

I am familiar with dplyr so happy to see a solution around it. Ideally i don't want to use a for loop, but could do if the best solution. In my example above i used zero values for my non-NA cases, that can be anything, doesn't have to be 0.

thanks! :)

Comment: please paste the code for your dataframe

Comment: Why your last row has `Output` `0`, shouldn't it be `2` if you are looking for the incremental count?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cumsum` to count up `NA` within each group. An `ifelse` will only assign these counts to `NA`, otherwise will include 0 in `output`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Region) %>%
  mutate(Output = ifelse(is.na(Value), cumsum(is.na(Value)), 0))
```

**Output**

```
  Region Value Output
  <chr>  <int>  <dbl>
1 A          5      0
2 B          2      0
3 B         NA      1
4 A         NA      1
5 A          9      0
6 A         NA      2
7 A          4      0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, this is exactly what i needed without using any loop or other complex way of doing it! wasn't familiar with cumsum, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new column with is.na(value), than group by region and than use cumsum() to create your desired output

```
df%>%mutate(output=ifelse(!is.na(Value), 0, 1))%>%group_by(Region, output)%>%mutate(output=cumsum(output))

# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   Region, output [5]
  Region Value output
  <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A          5      0
2 B          2      0
3 B         NA      1
4 A         NA      1
5 A          9      0
6 A         NA      2
7 A          4      0
```